# What will make computer parts (PSU, MB, SSD, HDD, Fans) last longer: keeping PC always on or turning off regularly

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, shutdown, fan, temperature

Before I continue, there is no answer to this question on `StackExchange`.

One is

> Is it harmful to keep PC always on? [duplicate]

a duplicate  of

> Is it better to leave your computer on all the time?

which is completely removed.

---

When I turn off my PC, it's usually time for leaving my study room. When I leave, I open the window to ventilate the room. At the moment it's -5C degrees outside. Computer parts can heat up to 100C but most of the parts temperature is around 40C-60C degrees.

I've started to think, that regular *cooling* and then *heating* is not good for transistors and other parts? Is this true?

Is it better for hardware to keep it always on and thus ***prevent regular temperature changes***?

Comment: I hope you don't keep the window open all night long?

Comment: @frlan Why not? It's good to constantly get fresh air.

Comment: To save the environment it is better to turn the devices you are not using always off, I would say! :)

Comment: It's completely enough to open window for maybe 5-10min. Time above might will cool down walls etc. which is increasing costs for heating quiet a lot. Beside of this: turn off your devices. Always, if not needed. Maybe sending them to some standby mode. The only part might have issues with is your hard disc.

Comment: I'm aware about environment! Non of your comments answer my question: `if it's bad for computer transistors and other parts to undergo regular temperature changes`. In case switching off  brings damage - eventually it will also impact environment and most likely much more than keeping your PC on.. think again.

Comment: Angry downvoters - please comment (explain). :D

Comment: It seems like you want an argument more than an answer.

Comment: Yes, I do want a good argument or an answer, backed with evidences, rather than ephemeral idea of `general consensus`.

Comment: Not sure what is classed as evidence but http://lifehacker.com/5940176/is-it-bad-to-shutdown-my-computer-regularly-or-leave-it-on-all-the-time and http://www.howtogeek.com/128507/htg-explains-should-you-shut-down-sleep-or-hibernate-your-laptop/ and http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-computers-sleep/ provide some arguments. Your question is not only too broad it's also too opinion based :(.  A computer obviously has many parts to it - and often the reason to why it really failed is not obvious. Meaning many conclusions are IMO incorrect or based upon myths.

Comment: Sorry, a closed question cant be answered. At least you have an answer :) To those who downvoted, I think that is harsh. The question is off topic yes, but the question is polite and well worded and doesn't deserve so many downvotes! Just having it closed makes the point, or at least leaving a comment explaining it is off topic!

Comment: @Dave, thank you! The fact it has so many down-votes proves the proposition, that votes are more important than question itself. Moderators close the question and upvotes other moderator's senseless answer. If you downvote a question and vote to close it, then there is no reason to answer it. If it wasn't the case, then my question would be moved to appropriate StackExchange site. By the way articles you sent me is good to read but they don't seem to talk about the reality of my question. It seems that the idea of power-saving has most effect on people's minds, than actual situation itself.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev moderators had no involvement in putting your question on hold. Personally I think your question is not unreasonable but it is a bit broad, there are too many factors that affect the resistance to temperature changes. Thermal expansion between components and within components themselves can be difficult to predict and estimate their impact. There is also a problem with your question title, it sounds like you are asking us to recommend products in the title and it doesn't match up with your question body...

Comment: @Mokubai could you please recommend where on StackExchange I could post this kind of question to get competent answer?

P.S. I will edit my question's title.

Answer (score 2):

The general consensus is that you're probably slightly better off turning the computer off. When the computer is off, it's safe from spikes, surges, and overheating, which are the kinds of things that can really shorten its life. The heating and cooling, if not rapid or extreme, is not as bad as being hot all the time. Of course, turning the computer off when it's not in use saves power too.

Comment: In case you have power filter/stabilizers, which makes `spikes and surges` not a problem and `overheating` too, because I can leave my PC idle (when consumption of 1500W PSU drops to about 30-50W). Yes, it's rapid from about 50C to 10C (as PC on the floor and thats where the cold air goes).

Comment: While saving power is good, broken parts `will damage environment MUCH more` (as they have to be replaced) than keeping it on (in case it saves/lengthens it's lifespan), right?

Comment: You can argue this however you want. Nevertheless, the answer I gave is the general consensus. Reducing the life of parts usually won't damage the environment because the parts generally get thrown out due to obsolescence before they break anyway.

Comment: `general consensus` - most of the time, is far away from truth!
I would rather like to hear or read about properly made scientific experiments on that matter (changing temperature for electronic parts and its lifespan).

Before writing this question I was aware of 'general consensus'. .. and in case my point stands, _prematurely_ broken parts will damage the environment much more. (as most of them contain precious metals, has to be reworked, utilized and etc.)

Comment: Whatever evidence they have, it won't be with your electrical conditions and your equipment. So the best you can do is go with the general consensus, which is pretty much that it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Really not sure what makes you think that!? Thanks, pal for your thoughts anyway! It `doesn't help` me at all `nor answers` my question!

Comment: If its plugged in it isn't "safe from spikes".  As for the general consensus I don't agree with it.

Comment: @Ramhound :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surge_protector

Comment: @lliaRostovtsev I am trying to agree with you.  I am just pointing out that the supporting statements to turn your computer off has holes in them.  Given that I have ran the same hardware for over 5 years and the only thing I ever touched was a failed fan I exceeded the lifespan of the products and I never shut the hardware off.  I also had memory fail on me but that has nothing to do with keeping it on ( at least one fail condition was caused by weather ).

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, I understood now, sorry. I just want to find best possible solution for all (environment and myself) and seem not to get right answer (understanding from people of what I want/mean)